# Difference between "crontab -e" & editing crontab file manually?

Tags: linux, centos, bash, redhat, cron

I noticed some people use "crontab -l" to view cronjobs and "crontab -e" to edit them. However there are also times where people manually modify "/etc/crontab" to view/add/remove cronjobs.

Both methods work fine, the only thing I noticed is that cronjobs added with "crontab -e" doesn't show up inside "/etc/crontab" even though it still runs normally.

I'd like to know what are the differences between these 2 methods? Are there any advantages/disadvantages over each other?

PS. I'm on CentOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal per-user crontabs that you edit with `crontab -e` are located in `/var/spool/cron`.

`/etc/crontab` holds a "system-wide" crontab maintained by the system administrator.

There's typically also a `/etc/cron.d` directory where installed software can add entries.